# Rolling window over irregular time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have an irregular time series of events (posts) using `xts`, and I want to calculate the number of events that occur over a rolling weekly window (or biweekly, or 3 day, etc). The data looks like this:

```
                    postid
2010-08-04 22:28:07    867
2010-08-04 23:31:12    891
2010-08-04 23:58:05    901
2010-08-05 08:35:50    991
2010-08-05 13:28:02   1085
2010-08-05 14:14:47   1114
2010-08-05 14:21:46   1117
2010-08-05 15:46:24   1151
2010-08-05 16:25:29   1174
2010-08-05 23:19:29   1268
2010-08-06 12:15:42   1384
2010-08-06 15:22:06   1403
2010-08-07 10:25:49   1550
2010-08-07 18:58:16   1596
2010-08-07 21:15:44   1608
```

which should produce something like

```
                    nposts
2010-08-05 00:00:00     10
2010-08-06 00:00:00      9
2010-08-07 00:00:00      5
```

for a 2-day window. I have looked into `rollapply`, `apply.rolling` from `PerformanceAnalytics`, etc, and they all assume regular time series data. I tried changing all of the times to just the day the the post occurred and using something like `ddply` to group on each day, which gets me close. However, a user might not post every day, so the time series will still be irregular. I could fill in the gaps with 0s, but that might inflate my data a lot and it's already quite large.

What should I do?

Comment: The solution for this doesn't currently exist in the xts package, but this request comes up enough that I've started to think about including a solution.

Comment: Do you have an update @JoshuaUlrich? Or something to the effect of the answer below that will fill in missing days with zeroes or NAs data so we can then use `rollapply`? I guess I can use `merge`...

Comment: @flodel: this question doesn't necessitate what I thought it did (see my answer). I thought they wanted to look back `n` days at every observation in their original series, which is a much more difficult problem to solve.

Comment: Well, I have to admit I did not read the question carefully and stopped at the title. I am indeed looking for the more complex case. My data is not super sparse so I am going to use `merge` to make the time series regularly spaced.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using xts:

```
x <- structure(c(867L, 891L, 901L, 991L, 1085L, 1114L, 1117L, 1151L, 
  1174L, 1268L, 1384L, 1403L, 1550L, 1596L, 1608L), .Dim = c(15L, 1L),
  index = structure(c(1280960887, 1280964672, 1280966285, 
  1280997350, 1281014882, 1281017687, 1281018106, 1281023184, 1281025529, 
  1281050369, 1281096942, 1281108126, 1281176749, 1281207496, 1281215744),
  tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"),
  .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"),
  .indexTZ = "", tzone = "")
# first count the number of observations each day
xd <- apply.daily(x, length)
# now sum the counts over a 2-day rolling window
x2d <- rollapply(xd, 2, sum)
# align times at the end of the period (if you want)
y <- align.time(x2d, n=60*60*24)  # n is in seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

```
# n = number of days
n <- 30
# w = window width. In this example, w = 7 days
w <- 7

# I will simulate some data to illustrate the procedure
data <- rep(1:n, rpois(n, 2))

# Tabulate the number of occurences per day:
# (use factor() to be sure to have the days with zero observations included)
date.table <- table(factor(data, levels=1:n))  

mat <- diag(n)
for (i in 2:w){
  dim <- n+i-1
  mat <- mat + diag(dim)[-((n+1):dim),-(1:(i-1))]
  }

# And the answer is.... 
roll.mean.7days <- date.table %*% mat
```

Seems to be not too slow (although the `mat` matrix will get dimensions n*n). I tried to replace n=30 with n=3000 (which creates a matrix of 9 million elements = 72 MB) and it still was reasonable fast on my computer. For very big data sets, try on a subset first.... It will also be faster to use some of the functions in the Matrix package (bandSparse) to create the `mat` matrix.

Comment: This is a nice way to apply a rolling window to something, but if you don't give an example showing how to apply this to an actual time serie (express as POSIXct date-time objects as in the original question), it hardly answers the question.

Comment: With a vectors of irregularly-spaced POSIXct objects `data <- sample(seq(as.POSIXct("2012/01/01"),as.POSIXct("2012/01/31"),by="hours"), 30)`, you can replace your `date.table` line by: `date.table <- table(cut(data,"days"))` and then proceed as you did, and it should do the trick.

Comment: plannapus, thanks for your additions regarding POSIXct objects.

Comment: any easy way to extend this to sum not just number of posts, but a factor - e.g. number of authors posting...?

Answer (score 0):

With runner one can [apply any R function](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/apply_any_r_function.html) on rolling windows. What OP requires is to calculate function (length) on rolling window only at specified time-points. 
Using `runner` user needs to specify `at` argument to indicate on what time-points output should be calculated. We can just pass vector of time-points to `runner` which we created on a side as a `POSIXt` sequence.
To make a `runner` time-dependent one has to specify `idx` by dates corresponding to `x` object. Length of the window can be set as `k = "2 days"`

```
at <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010-08-05 00:00:00"), 
          by = "1 days",
          length.out = 4)

# [1] "2010-08-05 CEST" "2010-08-06 CEST" "2010-08-07 CEST" "2010-08-08 CEST"


runner::runner(
  x = x$postid,
  k = "2 days",
  idx = x$datetime,
  at = at,
  f = length
)
# [1]  3 10  9  5
```