# Create new column based on condition that exists within a rolling date

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table, dplyr, date-range

To make this question more generalized, I believe it could also be rephrased as: **Creating a rolling temporally sensitive factor variable**. Though an uncommon requirement, this could be utilized for many different data sources.

I have a series of `non-uniform time data` with > 1 record per day for thousands of users. I want to create a new column `player_type` that keeps track of a rolling 30 day definition of their behavior. The behavior is defined by what games they play; the column `'games'` is a factor of gameA, gameB.

There are thus three types of behaviors:

1. Exclusively plays GameA - `'A'`
2. Exclusively plays GameB - `'B'`
3. Plays both games - `'Hybrid'`

I want to use this new column to see the changes in their play behavior over time, as well as counting the number of players in each group throughout time, to see how they change.

**The time series is highly irregular for each player.** Players can play multiple types of games per day, or not play any games for many months. The time series is irregular per player such that a record is only created when the player plays a game, thus I expect a solution might use a filter something like:

`interval(current_date, current_date - new_period(days=30)` (using lubridate).

Here is an example data set. Keep in mind this it is simplified and tests a rolling 1 day change, so simple methods checking the record before will not actually work.
If you are able to make a better data set, please advise and I will edit this post.

```
p <- c( 1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   2,   6,   6,   6)

g <- c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')

d <- seq(as.Date('2014-10-01'), as.Date('2014-10-9'), by=1)

df <- data.frame(player_id = p, date = d, games = g)
```

As output I require:

```
 player_id       date games   type
1         1 2014-10-01     A      A (OR NA)
2         1 2014-10-02     B Hybrid
3         1 2014-10-03     B      B
4         2 2014-10-04     A      A (OR NA)
5         2 2014-10-05     B Hybrid
6         2 2014-10-06     A Hybrid
7         6 2014-10-07     A      A (OR NA)
8         6 2014-10-08     B Hybrid
9         6 2014-10-09     B      B
```

The solution should be something like, `apply` through the columns, and apply a function which checks back 30 days in time, and an `ifelse()` statement to see what games they played.

This is a very similar post - and should help solve this problem. [How do I do a conditional sum which only looks between certain date criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020207/how-do-i-do-a-conditional-sum-which-only-looks-between-certain-date-criteria)

I have also explored, `rowwise()` and conditional `mutates()` using dplyr, however the catch is the historical time component for me.

Thanks for all the help! I can't thank this forum enough. I'll be checking back frequently.

Comment: In your real data, do you need to check for each row, all of the previous 30 rows or do you need to check the previous row (as in this example) but the delta between rows will always be 30 days?

Comment: I need to check the previous 30 days (by player). This could be many rows, or less then 30 rows. The delta between rows is not consistent. _They could play both games on the same day, or not play  either game for months at a time._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that I understood it right, here's a `data.table` way using `foverlaps()` function.

Create `dt` and set key as shown below:

```
dt <- data.table(player_id = p, games = g, date = d, end_date = d)
setkey(dt, player_id, date, end_date)

hybrid_index <- function(dt, roll_days) {
    ivals = copy(dt)[, date := date-roll_days]
    olaps = foverlaps(ivals, dt, type="any", which=TRUE)
    olaps[, val := dt$games[xid] != dt$games[yid]]
    olaps[, any(val), by=xid][(V1), xid]
}
```

We create a dummy data.table `ivals` (for intervals), and for each row, we specify the *start* and the *end* dates. Note that by specifying *end_date* identical as `dt$end_date`, we'll definitely have one match (and this is deliberate) - this'll give you the non-NA version you ask for.

[With some minor changes here, you can get the `NA` version, but I'll leave that to you (assuming this answer is right).]

With that we simply find which ranges from `ivals` overlaps with `dt`, *for each* `player_id`. We get the matching indices. From there it's straightforward. If a player's game is non-homogeneous, then we return the corresponding index of `dt` from `hybrid_index`. And we replace those indices with "hybrid".

```
# roll days = 1L
dt[, type := games][hybrid_index(dt, 1L), type := "hybrid"]
#    player_id games       date   end_date   type
# 1:         1     A 2014-10-01 2014-10-01      A
# 2:         1     B 2014-10-02 2014-10-02 hybrid
# 3:         1     B 2014-10-03 2014-10-03      B
# 4:         2     A 2014-10-04 2014-10-04      A
# 5:         2     B 2014-10-05 2014-10-05 hybrid
# 6:         2     A 2014-10-06 2014-10-06 hybrid
# 7:         6     A 2014-10-07 2014-10-07      A
# 8:         6     B 2014-10-08 2014-10-08 hybrid
# 9:         6     B 2014-10-09 2014-10-09      B

# roll days = 2L
dt[, type := games][hybrid_index(dt, 2L), type := "hybrid"]
#    player_id games       date   end_date   type
# 1:         1     A 2014-10-01 2014-10-01      A
# 2:         1     B 2014-10-02 2014-10-02 hybrid
# 3:         1     B 2014-10-03 2014-10-03 hybrid
# 4:         2     A 2014-10-04 2014-10-04      A
# 5:         2     B 2014-10-05 2014-10-05 hybrid
# 6:         2     A 2014-10-06 2014-10-06 hybrid
# 7:         6     A 2014-10-07 2014-10-07      A
# 8:         6     B 2014-10-08 2014-10-08 hybrid
# 9:         6     B 2014-10-09 2014-10-09 hybrid
```

To illustrate the idea clearly, I've created a function and copied `dt` inside the function. But you can avoid that and add the dates in `ivals` directly to `dt` and make use of `by.x` and `by.y` arguments in `foverlaps()`. Please look at `?foverlaps`.

Comment: This is **fantabulous**. Verified that it is working on my real data. Very insightful answer. Thank you.