# dplyr: grouping and summarizing/mutating data with rolling time windows

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr, lubridate

I have irregular timeseries data representing a certain type of transaction for users.  Each line of data is timestamped and represents a transaction at that time.  By the irregular nature of the data some users might have 100 rows in a day and other users might have 0 or 1 transaction in a day.

The data might look something like this:

```
data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
  date = c("2015-01-01", 
           "2015-01-01", 
           "2015-01-05", 
           "2015-01-25",
           "2015-02-15",
           "2015-05-05", 
           "2015-01-01", 
           "2015-08-01", 
           "2015-01-01"),
  n_widgets = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,2,4,5)
)

   id       date n_widgets
1  1 2015-01-01         1
2  1 2015-01-01         2
3  1 2015-01-05         3
4  1 2015-01-25         4
5  1 2015-02-15         4
6  2 2015-05-05         5
7  2 2015-01-01         2
8  3 2015-08-01         4
9  4 2015-01-01         5
```

Often I'd like to know some rolling statistics about users.  For example: for this user on a certain day, how many transactions occurred in the previous 30 days, how many widgets were sold in the previous 30 days etc.

Corresponding to the above example, the data should look like:

```
   id     date    n_widgets  n_trans_30  total_widgets_30
1  1 2015-01-01         1           1             1
2  1 2015-01-01         2           2             3
3  1 2015-01-05         3           3             6
4  1 2015-01-25         4           4             10
5  1 2015-02-15         4           2             8
6  2 2015-05-05         5           1             5
7  2 2015-01-01         2           1             2
8  3 2015-08-01         4           1             4
9  4 2015-01-01         5           1             5
```

If the time window is daily then the solution is simple: `data %>% group_by(id, date) %>% summarize(...)`

Similarly if the time window is monthly this is also relatively simple with lubridate: `data %>% group_by(id, year(date), month(date)) %>% summarize(...)`

However the challenge I'm having is how to setup a time window for an arbitrary period: 5-days, 10-days etc.

There's also the `RcppRoll` library but both `RcppRoll` and the rolling functions in `zoo` seem more setup for regular time series.  As far as I can tell these window functions work based on the number of rows instead of a specified time period -- the key difference is that a certain time period might have a differing number of rows depending on date and user.

For example, it's possible for user 1, that the number of transactions in the 5 days previous of `2015-01-01` is equal to 100 transactions and for the same user the number of transactions in the 5 days previous of `2015-02-01` is equal to 5 transactions.  Thus looking back a set number of rows will simply not work.

Additionally, there is another SO thread discussing rolling dates for irregular time series type data ([Create new column based on condition that exists within a rolling date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206924/create-new-column-based-on-condition-that-exists-within-a-rolling-date)) however the accepted solution was using `data.table` and I'm specifically looking for a `dplyr` way of achieving this.

I suppose at the heart of this issue, this problem can be solved by answering this question: how can I `group_by` arbitrary time periods in `dplyr`.  Alternatively, if there's a different `dplyr` way to achieve above without a complicated `group_by`, how can I do it?

EDIT: updated example to make nature of the rolling window more clear.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using SQL:

```
library(sqldf)

dd <- transform(data, date = as.Date(date))
sqldf("select a.*, count(*) n_trans30, sum(b.n_widgets) 'total_widgets30' 
       from dd a 
       left join dd b on b.date between a.date - 30 and a.date 
                         and b.id = a.id
                         and b.rowid <= a.rowid
       group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  id       date n_widgets n_trans30 total_widgets30
1  1 2015-01-01         1         1               1
2  1 2015-01-01         2         2               3
3  1 2015-01-05         3         3               6
4  1 2015-01-25         4         4              10
5  2 2015-05-05         5         1               5
6  2 2015-01-01         2         1               2
7  3 2015-08-01         4         1               4
8  4 2015-01-01         5         1               5
```

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is to expand your dataset to contain all possible days (using `tidyr::complete`), then use a rolling function (`RcppRoll::roll_sum`)

The fact that you have multiple observations per day is probably creating an issue though...

```
library(tidyr)
library(RcppRoll)
df2 <- df %>%
   mutate(date=as.Date(date))

## create full dataset with all possible dates (go even 30 days back for first observation)
df_full<- df2 %>%
 mutate(date=as.Date(date))  %>%
   complete(id, 
       date=seq(from=min(.$date)-30,to=max(.$date), by=1), 
       fill=list(n_widgets=0))

## now use rolling function, and keep only original rows (left join)
df_roll <- df_full %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n_trans_30=roll_sum(x=n_widgets!=0, n=30, fill=0, align="right"),
         total_widgets_30=roll_sum(x=n_widgets, n=30, fill=0, align="right")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(df2, by = c("date", "id", "n_widgets"))
```

The result is the same as yours (by chance)

```
     id       date n_widgets n_trans_30 total_widgets_30
  <dbl>     <date>     <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1 2015-01-01         1          1                1
2     1 2015-01-01         2          2                3
3     1 2015-01-05         3          3                6
4     1 2015-01-25         4          4               10
5     1 2015-02-15         4          2                8
6     2 2015-05-05         5          1                5
7     2 2015-01-01         2          1                2
8     3 2015-08-01         4          1                4
9     4 2015-01-01         5          1                5
```

But as said, it will fail for some days as it count last 30 obs, not last 30 days. So you might want first to `summarise` the information by day, then apply this.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED based on comment below.

You can try something like this for up to 5 days:

```
df %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(as.numeric(difftime(Sys.Date(), date, unit = 'days')) <= 5) %>%
  summarise(n_total_widgets = sum(n_widgets))
```

In this case, there are no days within five of current. So, it won't produce any output.

To get last five days for each ID, you can do something like this:

```
df %>%
   arrange(id, date) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(as.numeric(difftime(max(date), date, unit = 'days')) <= 5) %>%
   summarise(n_total_widgets = sum(n_widgets))
```

Resulting output will be:

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

     id n_total_widgets
  (dbl)           (dbl)
1     1               4
2     2               5
3     3               4
4     4               5
```

Comment: I edited...you can modify the difftime to suite exactly how you want it computed. Include current date, or not, or start counting from another date.

Comment: The above is certainly useful for when I'm comparing every row against the current date or against a set date.  However, every row will correspond to a different time window to check: i.e. for 2015-01-01, I need to aggregate with data from 2014-12-28 - 2015-01-01 and for 2015-01-25 I need to aggregate data from 2015-01-21 to 2015-01-25.

Comment: You can use `max(date)` instead of `Sys.Date()` for example so you have a different reference per group (`id`).

Comment: That's true but even within a specific `id`, each date window won't necessarily be compared against a single date.  For example, if `id = 1` has transactions at `2015-01-10`, `2015-01-11` and `2015-01-12`, then `max(date) = 2015-01-12`, but each of these 3 transactions has 3 different date windows that need to be aggregated over: `2015-01-06 to 2015-01-10`, `2015-01-07 to 2015-01-11` and `2015-01-08 to 2015-01-12` etc.  Each `id` could have hundreds of transactions months apart and I still need to build a window for each transaction date.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this while working on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407129/using-dplyr-to-count-and-mark-based-on-type-and-rolling-date-in-r/51407934#51407934)

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
  date = c("2015-01-01", 
           "2015-01-01", 
           "2015-01-05", 
           "2015-01-25",
           "2015-02-15",
           "2015-05-05", 
           "2015-01-01", 
           "2015-08-01", 
           "2015-01-01"),
  n_widgets = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,2,4,5)
)

count_window <- function(df, date2, w, id2){
  min_date <- date2 - w
  df2 <- df %>% filter(id == id2, date >= min_date, date <= date2)
  out <- length(df2$date)
  return(out)
}
v_count_window <- Vectorize(count_window, vectorize.args = c("date2","id2"))

sum_window <- function(df, date2, w, id2){
  min_date <- date2 - w
  df2 <- df %>% filter(id == id2, date >= min_date, date <= date2)
  out <- sum(df2$n_widgets)
  return(out)
}
v_sum_window <- Vectorize(sum_window, vectorize.args = c("date2","id2"))

res <- df %>% mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  mutate(min_date = date - 30,
         n_trans = v_count_window(., date, 30, id),
         total_widgets = v_sum_window(., date, 30, id)) %>% 
  select(id, date, n_widgets, n_trans, total_widgets)
res


id       date n_widgets n_trans total_widgets

1  1 2015-01-01         1       2             3
2  1 2015-01-01         2       2             3
3  1 2015-01-05         3       3             6
4  1 2015-01-25         4       4            10
5  1 2015-02-15         4       2             8
6  2 2015-05-05         5       1             5
7  2 2015-01-01         2       1             2
8  3 2015-08-01         4       1             4
9  4 2015-01-01         5       1             5
```

This version is fairly case specific but you could probably make a version of the functions that is more general.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity reasons I recommend [runner](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/) package which handles sliding window operations. In OP request window size `k = 30` and windows depend on date `idx = date`. You can use `runner` function which applies any R function on given window, and `sum_run`

```
library(runner)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(
    n_trans30 = runner(n_widgets, k = 30, idx = date, function(x) length(x)),
    n_widgets30 = sum_run(n_widgets, k = 30, idx = date),
  )

# id      date       n_widgets n_trans30 n_widgets30
#<dbl>   <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1    2015-01-01         1         1           1
# 1    2015-01-01         2         2           3
# 1    2015-01-05         3         3           6
# 1    2015-01-25         4         4          10
# 1    2015-02-15         4         2           8
# 2    2015-01-01         2         1           2
# 2    2015-05-05         5         1           5
# 3    2015-08-01         4         1           4
# 4    2015-01-01         5         1           5
```

**Important:** `idx = date` should be in ascending order.

For more go to [documentation](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/index.html) and [vignettes](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/articles/runner_examples.html)